# Javascript IntelliSence for Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code editor to start my Reactive tutorial. Though I have installed the extensions - Babel Javascript and Javascript(ES6) code snippets, I am not getting the IntelliSence. Can you please help here?

[image]

Comment: It should work in `.js` files, not in `.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the javascript code in `.js` file or inside `<script>` tag like this:

```
.
.
.
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
</script>
.
.
.
```